Understanding Time-Dependent Bilinear Forms in Partial Differential Equations
I am studying the time-dependent bilinear form associated with the Boussinesq equation, specifically:
\begin{equation*}
a(t; u, v) = \int_\Omega \left( u_x v_x + u_{xx} v_{xx} \right) dx,
\end{equation*}
where $u$ and $v$ are functions that belong to $H^2_0(\Omega)$. I have proved that the bilinear form is continuous in $H^2_0(\Omega)$, i.e., there exists $C>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
a(t; u, v) \leq C\|u\|_{H^2_0(\Omega)} \|v\|_{H^2_0(\Omega)}.
\end{equation*}
My question is: How should we interpret this time-dependent bilinear form in the context of partial differential equations? Are both $u$ and $v$ time-dependent? Specifically, how does the dependence on time affect properties like continuity and differentiability of $a(t; u(t), v(t))$? Are both $u$ and $v$ time-dependent?
Any insights or references on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

This bilinear form is not time-dependent.

$u$ and $v$ are maps $\mathbb{R}\to H^2_0(\Omega)$. It is a slight abuse of notation and it should be $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ inside the integral but they (and hence $a$) do depend on time

Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.
